# How to retrieve Member's participation history in TeamRoom's in VersionOne using API?

Tags: versionone

I want to get a history of `Member`s participation in `TeamRoom`s, or, if that is not possible, participation of a `Member` in `TeamRoom`s as of some date.

But it seems that `asof` influences the objects being requested themselves, not their participation links. Both these queries return latest participation, instead of participation as of specified date:

```
{
    "from": "Member",
    "select": [
        "Username",
        "Name",
        "ParticipatesIn.Name",
    ],
    "where": [
        "asof": "2016-01-01"
    ]
}
```

,

```
{
    "from": "TeamRoom",
    "select": [
        "Name",
        "Participants.Username",
        "Participants.Name"
    ],
    "where": [
        "asof": "2016-01-01"
    ]
}
```

And I do not see a `Participation` entity to query.

How to overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this suffice ?

```
http://localhost/VersionOne/rest-1.v1/Hist/TeamRoom?Sel=Name,Team.Name,Participants.Name,ChangeDate,CreateDate&where=Participants.Name='Mickey Mouse';ChangeDate>='2018-06-01'
```

That is using the History REST API end point.